# Extending CoreResultsWebPart - Setting defaults

Tags: web-part, search-results

I'm in a process of extending `CoreResultsWebPart` - I'm trying to create something like "Who is Blogging" to show you most recent blogs from people.
Following properties will be changed - so that when used it will be set as default.

1. XslLink (Done)
2. Location (to only Local Search Results)
3. Sorting

I'm unable to find how to setup `Location`. There is a property called Location which takes string. However I have tried with `"LocalSearchResults"` and I't doesn't work.

This is my code so far:

```
public class WhosBloggingWebPart : CoreResultsWebPart
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            base.UseLocationVisualization = false;
            base.XslLink = @"/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/WhosBloggingModule/WhosBloggingXSLT.xslt";

            this.Location = "LocalSearchResults";
            this.FixedQuery = "contenttype:post AND NOT Title:\"Welcome to your Blog!\" AND url:\"*/site/*\"";
            this.QueryNumber = QueryId.Query2;

            this.DefaultSort = ResultsView.Modified_Date;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the location value to `LocalSearchIndex`

```
this.Location = "LocalSearchIndex";
```

Comment: How do you know this? I spend hours going over msdn and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Luke I read the location property into a string variable then debuged the web part and watched the value as I set the property of the web part in the UI.

Comment: Nice. Good idea! I though it is actually documented somewhere.